# Positioning a div inside a div without affecting layout

Tags: css, css-float

I have a `div` (`div1`) that has its position, width, height, everything all set, and it is set externally, so I can't know ahead of time what those values are.

Inside and at the top of `div1` is another `div` (`div2`). I want `div2` to float on the right of `div1` without affecting the following information in `div1`.

I can add the attribute `position:absolute` and get `div2` to float and not affect the contents, however, I cannot get it to float on the right, even when applying `float:right`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

First, apply `position: relative` to your `div1`.

As it "won't work" when you have both `float: right` and `position: absolute` on your `div2`, you should replace the `float: right` rule with `right: 0`.

Comment: I can't use `position:relative;float:right;` because that affects the contents in the cell. I also can't use `position:absolute;right:0;` because div1 is positioned, and div2 is put at the far right of the window.

Comment: @steveo225: How is `div1` positioned? With `position: absolute`?

Comment: It is dynamic, set externally (via an AJAX load depending on the content being displayed). Meaning is could be absolute, relative, or just centered in the window.

Comment: Then I would suggest putting a div with position: relative in first, then put div2 in that with position: absolute; right: 0;

Comment: @steveo225: I don't think you're approaching this in the right way. If you're loading in AJAX content, surely you have *some* idea of what it is. And if you don't you can use Javascript to find out what positioning the loaded content is using. Or you could use Javascript to do the positioning. What I'm trying to say is: you're not giving us enough information.

Comment: Here is the deal. This is kind of an example of what I am doing. I have a parser that works server side and loaded via AJAX into a div styled by the content provider. Sometimes the information comes external to the site, say I parsed Wikipedia's article of the day and want the image to stay floating left like they have it. So I don't want to change whatever styling is provided by the content manager, I just want to add a small div in the top right, for example to put a copyright notice or something.

Comment: I still don't see why you can't use `position: relative` on a parent element, and `position: absolute` your copyright notice. But, let's pretend that's not an option. Have you considered loading the content from your server side parser into an iframe? That should free you from *whatever* positioning code is being used in the loaded content.

Comment: I got it. I had to add a third div (div3), with `position:relative` inside div1, then place div2 inside div3 with `position:absolute;right:0`. I hope this gets a little more straight forward as HTML5 and CSS3 start to become more commonplace.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
```

Comment: I also can't use `position:absolute;right:0;` because div1 is positioned, and div2 is put at the far right of the window.

Comment: Like thirtydot said, you will need to make sure div1 has position: relative;

Comment: Like I said, its style is set externally, so I don't have control. I can get div2 floating right, or not affecting the contents, but not both

Answer (score 1):

with just relative positioning?

```
<div style="height:300px;width:300px;position:relative;background-color:red">
  <div style="height:100px;width:100px;position:relative;float:right;background-color:yellow">
</div>
```

Comment: As noted, the position, width, etc. are set externally and can't be known ahead of time

Comment: are you able to consider javascript to check position and act accordingly?

Comment: I can check it, but I don't want to change it, because it looks correct, and there are too many possibilities to check and handle them all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing the other contents of div1 into another div, then setting a specified width on that div while keeping float:right on div2. Sounds like a sidebar style scenario.